# Encouraging attentive suggested edit reviewers to skip every uncontroversial review

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Some time ago, I asked [Qantas 94 Heavy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2074608/qantas-94-heavy) how he got such a high reject:accept ratio, and the answer was simple but blew my mind: *skipping anything that would likely be accepted just fine anyway by the unstoppable train of auto-acceptances*. Since then, I've followed that rule, with the result that I end up reviewing maybe 40 posts/day, many of which will probably either get properly accepted (by far the most common) or even properly rejected (once in a while) without my intervention. These I skip, which allows me to spend my 20 reviews on the edits that really need careful attention.

Since this technique focuses a more, shall we say, discerning eye on those edits that actually need it, and slows down approval on obvious posts a little bit more, it seems to be highly desirable for all reasonably savvy reviewers to follow this or something similar.

How many such reviewers already know of this trick, and how can we get more to use it?

Comment: related: [Additional requirement for Steward or Reviewer badge to help new reviewers learn about using “Skip”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232052/165773)

Comment: Er... I'm quite confused -- why should this be encouraged? Skipping reviews that you're not sure about is perfectly okay, skipping reviews to find the worst is okay too... but that's not to say *all* reviewers should be encouraged to do the latter.

Comment: @hichris123 Clearly we don't want *all* reviewers doing this, but I think Nathan is working under the assumption that encouraging more reviewers to follow these guidelines will not result in all the reviewers suddenly changing their review style en masse.

Comment: @hichris123: Stars is right; if I thought a meta post or two would result in robo-reviewers changing their ways, I'd just say "Hey guys, we should all be looking carefully at edits before approving them!" Problem solved! But here, the key is that there's a super-abundance of floating approve votes around, so even a fairly substantial increase in Skips instead of Approves would not noticeably hamper genuine edits.

Comment: What is the core problem with the Edit review queue that you're addressing?  Is it that reviewers are too often clicking Approve without even reading the Edits?  Or is it that too many trivial Edits are being Approved (and, by extension, that too many trivial Edits are being proposed in the first place)?  I try to reject trivial Edits if there are other plainly obvious changes that the proposer should have made and didn't.  But otherwise I feel I have no choice but to accept them if they do make the post more readable.

Comment: You should probably clarify that the motivation for adopting this behaviour is to better allocate a limited resource i.e. the 20 reviews you are allowed per day. Clicking "Approve" spends 1 of those, clicking "Skip" keeps it in your pocket for the next edit which may be more deserving of attentive review. (At least I think that's what you're driving at?)

Comment: @dg99: It's that there are too many reviewers approving things that are *wrong*. However, because there's a substantial cohort of reviewers that will approve nearly anything, the easiest way to get enough rejections on those edits that genuinely need it is to avoid wasting accepts on (perfectly good!) edits that will go through one way or another without your assistance. This could perhaps go into an answer, actually.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I thought I'd gotten that, but I'll see what I can do to clarify it more.

Comment: It's been my strategy for a long, long time - with all the robo-approvers around, "Skip" was effectively the same as "Approve". It got better when edit suggestions got locked during a review, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 27):

Here's something to try on for size.

The idea has come up in the comments that reviewers are obligated to click the button corresponding to their idea of the edit's merit: <kbd>Accept</kbd>, <kbd>Reject</kbd>, <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd>, <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>. This sounds highly plausible, or even so obvious it's hardly worth mentioning.

It's also wrong. <kbd>Skip</kbd> ***is always a correct action***, by virtue of never being wrong. Often it is the *best* action:

- Perhaps you're too distracted right now?
  <kbd>Skip</kbd>
- Perhaps you're annoyed at something, including the original post that's being edited?
  <kbd>Skip</kbd>
- Perhaps you want to save your reviews for more important things, like a post that's *not* 55 seconds from being close-del-voted into oblivion?
  <kbd>Skip</kbd>

Or, since many edits can be handled correctly by almost any reviewer, perhaps you want to spend your time and reviews on trickier edits that would be mishandled otherwise. For that, you need to 
        <kbd>Skip</kbd> the simple ones!

Do what you can to make the site better with the time you've got. <kbd>Skip</kbd> is often integral to that goal, just as someone is proverbially defined by what they say No to.

Comment: The problem with skipping is that if everyone is skipping than some reviews may never get finished. In the end I guess that every edit has merited a reviewer that carefully studies and judges it. Problem is: there are not enough reviewers of that type available for the necessary amount of reviews. Tweaking the system a bit will not change the situation much, is my guess, even if many people would hit skip a lot.

Comment: @Trilarion: If I thought all the robo-reviewers would take my advice, I would tell them to do their job. They won't, so there is not the slightest danger of "everyone skipping". That's just not plausible. (See my reply to hichris123 on the question.)