# Why simply "Approve" or "Reject" suggested edits after 2000 rep?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

After 2000 rep, I'm able to edit posts and have the changes immediately take effect. However, if I see a suggested edit from someone without that privilege, my review options fall into two categories: implement my decision unilaterally and immediately (with "Improve" or "Reject and Edit"), or don't (with "Approve" or "Reject").

What are the advantages to choosing the latter?

Comment: If a suggested edit defaces or drastically modifies a post, you would need something else to edit for a "reject and edit". Now, you could just add a space...

Answer (score 5):

> What are the advantages to choosing the latter?

There's no advantages. You are simply doing your "job". You should be reviewing the suggestions. If they look good and don't need any fixin' up then approve. If they are terrible or simply not going to help the post any then reject.

The advantage actual comes with the other two options, I'd say.

If the edit suggestion is a nice one but there were some things missed (happens often) then improve it. This makes the post better and the user suggesting the edit gets the credit they deserve (by the way of +2 rep).

If the suggestion is bad or they missed a whole lot that they have tried to improve but you feel you can make it better, then reject it and edit the post yourself.

Comment: If an edit is terrible, I "Reject," and it goes through anyway due to robo-reviewers, I may have done my "review suggested edits" job, but perhaps not my "be a 2k+ rep user" job, and certainly not my "improve the quality of the site's content" job. Should I abandon my "review suggested edits" job, or is there a compelling reason to favor it over the other jobs?

Comment: I don't think so. Not unless you can do it in an appropriate way (i.e. rejecting and improving with a valid edit and not just an arbitrary edit). Robo-reviewers are something everyone on the site is well aware of. Unfortunately, that is a separate issue and there hasn't been a great way to handle it so far, that I'm aware of. Making an arbitrary edit because it might get through isn't solving the underlying issue.

Comment: Hmm... so should I just review the suggested edit and forget about it? Just today, I've seen one bad suggested edit (changed the code to introduce a crashing error) get two approvals before finally getting rejected, and a great edit (made a question much more readable, removed tags from title, etc.) get a rejection before finally getting approved. In both cases, the edit took about an hour to be resolved. Wouldn't it be better to equip my Editing Sword of +2k Rep?

Comment: And yes, I would be making valid edits if I were to do this (there's always room for tweaks).

Comment: Then definitely, as I said in my answer, reject and edit

Comment: Okay; I'll keep my Editing Sword of +2k Rep in my inventory, but only equip it for bosses. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: To generally help combat robo-reviewers, my advice is to [skip uncontroversial suggestions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292007/4099598) rather than spending one of your 20 daily review actions doing what a robo-reviewer will do anyway. Save those for the important edits.