# What to do when I find a user suggesting a large number of trivial edits?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, spam

While reviewing posts, I sometimes find a user who suggests a large number of trivial edits.

For example just adding or removing a single tag with no other changes, or only removing "thanks" from posts that have many other things in need of fixing.

I usually reject these suggested edits as I see them, but it can become annoying when I see many from the same user in a row. I feel like I'm wasting my review votes when this user is just going to keep suggesting trivial edits.

**Is there a more effective way to stop this kind of behavior?**

Comment: _"as rejecting them is simply wasting my limited reviews."_ Eh, no it's not. Rejections are a crucial part of the review process. In fact, too many edits that should get rejected pass through the queue due to people robo-reviewing. Good edits will get accepted eventually, bad edits _have_ to get as many rejection votes as they can, to counter people not paying attention. Imo, skipping those is a waste of your limited reviews.

Comment: @Cerbrus I understand your point and thank you for showing the correct way of doing things. I believed that may be admins can handle these edits more swiftly than me.

Comment: In this case, that may be true indeed. But I don't think that means you should skip those reviews.

Comment: He shouldn't be doing this without community supervision anyway tbh, so even if he did have 2k rep he would still show up as a problematic editor

Comment: @Sammaye: tag edits are fine if you have the 2k rep privilege.

Comment: @Cerbrus this extensively I would think that it would be changing too much without community consultation wouldn't you? What happens if the community does not agree with your new tag edits?

Comment: Then someone can flag it for mod attention.

Comment: @Cerbrus or it can be prevented in the first place by posting in meta, like burninate request

Comment: Not all tag edits need to be discussed though. It comes down to 2k+ users using common sense when they feel some tag is misplaced or missing.

Comment: "Can an administrator look into all tag edits done by this user?" - they are moderators, not admins.

Comment: Update: The edit was later approved by community! ;/

Comment: @DhruvJoshi related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292007/how-to-encourage-attentive-suggested-edit-reviewers-to-skip-every-straightforwar

Comment: Classic example of someone making a useless edit that 4 people approved (what were they thinking), but only 1 review saw and caught and rejected.  I've since undone this edit as it was on my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13099908   How is a user with almost no rep, able to change a 6 year old accepted answer with 66 up votes!?!?!??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**From the help center page on the editing privilege:**

> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.
> <sub>https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit</sub>

Under normal circumstances, this doesn't warrant you going out of your way to intervene; however, edits bump questions on the active page, and a large number of these edits will fill the active tab with old questions and annoy the regulars of the associated tags.

This becomes especially egregious when the user has less than 2,000 reputation points (they do not have the editing privilege), because it can take up to five users each spending one of their twenty review votes for the day to approve or reject each edit.

If you feel that the situation warrants intervention, and you want to take it upon yourself to do so, you could either:

- choose "Reject and Edit" for each one that you find, this automatically commits the rejection and overwrites it with your edit. The downside of this is that it takes a lot more time to fix one of these edits than to make five more; or,
- invite the user to a new chatroom and explain why editing (or submitting edits to) large numbers of inactive posts is problematic. Let them know that we don't discourage editing in general, but edits should be thorough and meaningful. There is no reason to edit a zero score question from five years ago that no one cares about.

If you feel that the situation warrants an intervention, but you don't want to take it upon yourself to do so (for whatever reason), you could either:

- bring it to the attention of other users in chat (for example the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room); or,
- use a custom moderator flag on one of the edited posts. Describe (in detail) the edits that are being made which you feel are unnecessary and problematic, and link to some of the relevant edits.
  Moderators can and will decline these flags if they disagree with you; make sure it is not border-line.

**Related:**

- [Encouraging attentive suggested edit reviewers to skip every uncontroversial review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292007/how-to-encourage-attentive-suggested-edit-reviewers-to-skip-every-straightforwar)
- [A turd by any other name... yeah, it's still a turd. (Except when it isn't)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308140/4639281)