# Low-rep user making wholesale tag edits

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits, new-users

As in [What to do when I find a user suggesting a large number of trivial edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303373/found-someone-making-large-number-of-tag-edits)...

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3387453/rasteve?tab=activity) is making wholesale tag edits, removing [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic).

All those edits are going for review, due to their rep.

There is no meta post discussing this wholesale activity.

Can a mod step in and stop them?

Comment: I'm hardly new, but yes I am the one removing BASIC tag for questions regarding VBA, VB.NET and VB6.  There are a number of questions using the BASIC tag with no votes/views because they had the wrong tag.

Comment: The burst of tag-only edits going into the review queues stands out as a problematic-editor indicator. When editing, you shouldn't just be editing tags, but also other problems with the post. And it's worth remembering that tags aren't the only reason questions don't get upvotes.

Comment: I've added comments to any edits, and almost every single one has been accepted.  There is no redefinition of the [tag:basic] just that some questions were linked to the wrong tag.  I guess users couldn't find results for "visual basic" so used basic instead?

Comment: @rasteve [See my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305575/1768232)

Comment: @rasteve - Of course the edits were accepted; If each one is evaluated on their own merits, many are "good". Also, and unfortunately, the reviewers don't always apply the "what else needs to be edited here" measure, so good-but-incomplete edits have a decent chance of making it through. The problem I'm alerting here is one of scale and lack of community involvement - Durron's answer sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>This was going to be a comment so I could ping @rasteve but it got too long so I made it into an answer. The word **you** here refers to @rasteve, not @Mogsdad</sub>

Large scale edits like this one **should always be discussed in meta first**; if it's determined that you (or anyone interested in making large scale edits) are correct, the community will get involved and *help you*. But, if you're wrong for some reason, you will get downvoted on Meta and people will explain why you're wrong.

Doing things to hundreds or thousands of posts **on your own** is heavily frowned upon, [**even for moderators!!**](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8058/182300) You've been a member for a year, having below 500 rep doesn't give you the right to edit posts on your own for a reason, you are most likely not familiar enough with the system to realize something about the importance of having community support before doing something like this.

Note: at no point in this answer have I commented on whether removing [basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic) from questions about [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) is a good or bad idea, because *that's not the point*. The point is: **involve the community first** by making a meta post, and then, **if it has support,** go ahead with the cleanup.

Now, I should point out that *many of the questions you're editing require much more editing than simply tag removal*. Note that questions that are improperly tagged have a higher probability of being lower quality and need community revision. By removing the tag, you make it **more difficult** for the community to find and fix these questions, even though your tag removal may be completely justified.

Comment: I didn't intend to make wholesale changes just obvious problems with questions I came across.  I have been making amendments to spellings/layouts where I see them, and downvoting bad questions.  I think you guys hit the panic button too early!

Comment: I have only proposed to remove the basic tag where an existing visual basic specific tag already exists on the questions.  In a small number I have suggested replacements (where they are missing).

Comment: @rasteve It doesn't matter. If you're going to bulk edit a large number of posts, make a post here on Meta about it; get the community involved and then maybe we'll help you!

Comment: @rasteve Why not make the meta post now? Explain the patterns you're seeing, and what you would propose to do about it. Back it up with some numbers. You might even make a case for [tag:basic] being ambiguous, and turn the request into a [tag:burnination-request]. You might be surprised at the support you get - but I won't be.

Comment: I'll let you guys go through stats etc.  I was just flagging questions with wrong tags as I came across them.  I also added a lot of missing visual-foxpro tags to questions that had them missing. Was doing the same for basic tag.  I was only flagging obvious stuff.  I don't think the tag should be removed (basic is a language).  I don't mind making a suggestion to the tag wiki to make it clearer.

Comment: So with this answer does that mean I can't suggest edits for the basic tag any more without a meta discussion?

Comment: @rasteve Of course you can, just not dozens or hundreds. It looked like you were "systematically looking for questions to edit" not "I'm reading questions, oh by the way I'm going to propose an edit"