# Should I approve a suggested edit fixing a broken link in an answer I have flagged as "not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I am not sure if the "no improvement whatsoever" reject reason is appropriate, although it is the closest to appropriate as none of the other reasons are really applicable at all.

I think the edit is superfluous, not because it doesn't improve the answer, but because it improves an answer that is basically a comment with a link in it that doesn't (in my opinion) have any value as an answer.

But saying there is no improvement whatsoever doesn't seem right when it actually does make a little improvement, and if other people disagree with me that it is not really an answer, then the edit actually is useful.

I have encountered a few suggested edits like this before and so far have just skipped them because I was not sure what to do. What should be my guidelines for evaluating this type of situation? Should I approve or reject edits based on the usefulness of the edit regardless of the usefulness of the thing being edited?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### A turd by any other name... yeah, it's still a turd. <sup><sup><sub>* Except when it isn't</sub></sup></sup>

So, we're told that if a suggested edit improves the quality a post at all whatsoever, then it should be approved. Personally, I think that's a load of horse-poopie but I digress. The important thing to note in situations such as this is that **VLQ and NaA flags are voided any time an edit is applied to a post**.

So even though a suggested edit *may* improve the quality of a post somewhat, there are still situations where "no improvement whatsoever" may still fit the bill.

- If the suggested edit *does not* void the reasons for the flag then it should not be approved.
- If the suggested edit *does* void the reasons for the flag then it should be approved.

The question you need to be asking yourself when reviewing these edits is either "*Is it still not an attempt to answer a question?*" or "*Does it still have severe content or formatting problems?*" depending on which flag was used.

In general turd polishing should be discouraged, but if the act of polishing happens to clean the turd from an otherwise useful post then you should go ahead and approve the suggested edit.

Comment: "we're told that if a suggested edit improves the quality a post at all whatsoever, then it should be approved" citation?

Comment: I take a very dim view of those who polish turds just to farm rep, and I think SO as a whole should too.

Comment: "Don't polish a turd" is always a valid reject often. Reject early and reject often. If a post is still crap with the edit, reject and flag.

Comment: But, but, but Mythbusters [makes it look so cool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiJ9fy1qSFI)

Comment: @Don'tPanic yeh, I'm not clicking on that that one LOL

Comment: "VLQ and NaA flags are voided any time an edit is applied to a post" only if the edit comes from the VLQ queue, organic edits don't invalidate NAA/VLQ. Score >0 invalidates VLQ flags.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course you should approve or reject edits based on the usefulness of the edit regardless of the usefulness of the thing being edited. The considerations (“Is the edit an enhancement?” and “Is the answer useless?”) are quite distinct and should be kept separate. The former is review, the latter voting.

Even if you don’t have the inclination or the skill to abstract relevant details from the link to bring the answer up to an acceptable standard you would nevertheless be helping someone else do so by facilitating finding the relevant link. Ideally of course that someone else would be you, having made such a good start, but *there are others*.

For a mere 525 entries from 10,347,735 questions to be in the Low Quality Posts queue is a sure sign that the system is coping - and would cope with a few more.

I take it you flagged as “not an answer” mainly or merely because it was a comment and a link but that the link information was relevant so you would not have flagged the answer had some of the content of the link been directly incorporated. If the link information is irrelevant then, link broken or not, you would presumably not have the dilemma you mention.