# Why do editors bother?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I see catastrophic questions.

Questions where it's evident the author didn't give a moment of thought to how they would come across for the reader.

Occasionally, a well-reputed reviewer comes along and improves the question on the behalf of the person who asked it.

Now, I am all for introducing improvements to questions and answers. I accepted such edits on content I posted myself, learnt some things and appreciated the help.

I also understand and am all for commenting on the question and letting the asker know what he/she should do to improve their question.

However I don't really understand the motivation behind fixing a catastrophic question on their behalf.

Helping out newbies is one thing, but doing the work for a person who is obviously just lazy is another.

So - I'm curious as to why people would spend their valuable time when it's obvious the asker didn't bother to, and also whether such edits are considered good practice in SO or frowned upon (since they might discourage the asker from doing the work him/herself)

Comment: They shouldn't. The common agreement is **DON'T EDIT TURDS**

Comment: Related: [A turd by any other name... yeah, it's still a turd. (Except when it isn't)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308140/4639281)

Answer (score 20):

> Occasionally, a well-reputed reviewer comes along and improves the question on the behalf of the person who asked it.

It's not just on behalf of the person who asked it, it's on behalf of the entire community.  That includes anyone who might want to answer the question and anyone who might come to it years later with the same question. If there is an on-topic question to be salvaged, then time spent salvaging it isn't wasted.

(That said, if there *isn't* a good question hiding somewhere within a post, don't feel bad if you don't want to waste effort editing it. Just vote to close it.  There's no sense in improving the grammar, spelling, and formatting on a post that doesn't contain a worthwhile question.)