# How can I rephrase this question to make it comply with the SO format?

Tags: support, scope

I had a question deleted after [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333678/question-on-hold-still-have-problems).

This is the question after I edited it to try to comply with the rules:

> I succesfully configured scss preprocessor with assetic in my project, but AFAIK there is no way I can do a SCSS @import using assetic (my main reason to use css preprocessors). The processing has to be done in a per-file basis. What I would want was to use one .scss in a bundle and can refence it from an @import in another bundle.
>
> How this can be done ? It doesn't need to be scss. I just need any preprocessing method that can do an @import.

How could I have rephrased it to make it appropriate?

**Edit**

Using comments below I came to this:

> I have followed the instructions here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/php.html
>
> to use scss preprocessor in my symfony project. The problem is that because I'm using a filter, the file is preprocessed by the filter and I can't use @import in a file to reference another file in other bundle
>
> How can I use @import for scss files using Symfony/assetic ?

Do you think it's better now ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question on hold still have problems?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333678/question-on-hold-still-have-problems)

Comment: Hi Nelson. The feedback you've been given regarding this question is probably correct, but I am not of the view that it was given with much kindness by one particular 42K user below. At least part of the _Meta_ community would not tolerate newer users having their questions referred to as "turds" and I will liaise with the individual concerned to see if I can get them to soften their general approach. We often forget about how language is not abstract, and we wind up using words that we would not dare to use in person.

Comment: In the short term, have you tried Reddit as a forum for posting your closed question?

Comment: I have started a Meta discussion about this: `meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333688`.

Comment: Is this dicussion still active ? can't find it

Comment: My bad, the link for future readers is `meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333867`, but it seems you found it already!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the comments of your previous meta question:

> I need to preprocess css, and the method I'm trying isn't working.

Rephrase your question to center around what you've tried and how it didn't work. Show the code you tried, your inputs and outputs if applicable, and any errors you received. If there's another way to do it, users can suggest it. If there's a way to correct how you tried to do it, users can suggest that.

Right now, your question is just broadly asking for ideas. Don't ask for ideas on how to do something, ask how to make what you've tried to do already work. Your question is currently too broad, as there could be countless ways to solve your problem. If you narrow it down to what you have tried and how it failed, you'll have a much better chance at an answer that will work for you.

If you haven't already, you may want to check out the resources linked in the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page of the help center. There are some really helpful resources there for writing good questions.

Comment: Can I post it here once I have reformulated it before I ask in SO ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira: "*Using toolX, I tried fooing the bar and I expect it to baz, but it went bat instead. How can I make it baz?*" is acceptable because you've narrowed the question down to a particular tool and you have a particular output in mind. "*toolX can't foo the bar. How do I foo the bar?*" is usually not acceptable, because it's turned into a request for tool suggestions, which is too broad and tends to attract the Wrong Kind™ of answers.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira The edit you posted is certainly a step in the correct direction. You need to post the code you've got in the question itself, however. If in the future the link goes dead, your question will be far less useful because it will no longer show what the full issue was.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I don't have the code anymore. I have made a try to configure this some months ago in a test copy of my project. I didn't succeded, got other tasks, deleted the test copy and left this issue behind. Now my project had a small break and I'm triyng again but it's useless to configure it all over again before knowing a way to do it differently than before.

Comment: I suggest trying to configure it again anyway. It might be that originally you did it incorrectly, though you tried the correct method. Maybe this time you end up doing it right, and the question is no longer needed. Yes, it will take time, and yes, it is not the fast and easy way. But Stack Overflow is not the fast and easy way, either. Your question needs to be useful for future visitors, and if the question isn't self contained, it can break and become less useful or even useless in the future.

Comment: ok... I'll do that and came back to tell how I did

Comment: @JDB: It's acceptable as long as the attempt at fooing the bar is clearly shown, in an MCVE.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of what the rest of the question says, the core of your question is

> *I just need any preprocessing method that can do an @import.*

This is **too broad**, **opinion based** and **asking for recommendations**. Plain and simple as long as this is the core of your question, you can't improve it with minor semantic edits to try and tweak it not to be better.

It basically says;

> *Recommend me a preprocessing method that can do an @import*

There is an entire conversation on [turd polishing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308139/should-i-approve-a-suggested-edit-fixing-a-broken-link-in-an-answer-i-have-flagg/308140#308140) that applies to this question just as much.

This is the core problem you are not asking a specific narrow question, you are asking for broad, sweeping generalizations which is asking for recommendations to a general class of problems; these are not acceptable questions **for good reasons** that are explained in the close description.

Just removing and re-phrasing the offending lines to say the same thing semantically with different words does not change the fact that it is still a request for recommendations.

#### Lets break it down:

Requirement Statement and Implicit Request for Recommendation:

> What I would want was to use one .scss in a bundle and can reference
> it from an @import in another bundle.

Implicit Request for Recommendation:

> Is there any way of making @import work from one bundle to another?

As long as you insist on this line of question there is nothing you can do to not fall afoul of at least one legitimate close reason, even marginally qualifying for more than one close reason is proof of a generally poor question for sure and this question legitimately qualifies for at least 3 close reasons.