# Bad edit (suggestion) comment "Fixed formatting"

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, edit-summary

How can I encourage an (<2K rep) editor to comment correctly about their edit? [This suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9684245) was declared as "fixed formatting" but indeed was a rework of the whole text part of the post. (As I found out, the suggesting user typically commented their edits this way.) I was up to *Reject* it with a hand written message about the problem, but the suggestion *was clearly an improvement* so rejecting seemed not right to me.

How should I deal in those cases, apart from *Skip* the lazy or cowardly solution?

Comment: Seriously guys. So many <2k editors don't bother adding a proper summary because they know their edits are going to get approved anyway. Why have the edit summary field then? I want an editor to show me that they know what they are doing - an accurate summary reflects that. In the same vein, I want to be able to reject a suggested edit if its summary fails to describe its contents. (2k editors need not apply - they generally know what they are doing and that is precisely why they have no editing restrictions.)

Comment: I think you should still Approve this Edit since it is helpful / improvement. The purpose of this comment is to help you to understand the edit correctly but in this case the comment is useless for that purpose :)

Comment: Honestly, that edit *is* mostly fixing formatting: fixing the code representation and improving legibility by putting the explaining text above the code making it better readable.

Comment: @planetmaker What is "the code of" a question or answer other than its text (including code snippets naturally)? I mean, the edit summary should reflect the change correctly, if it doesn't, it wastes the time of reviewers more than necessary. It is already hard to read two texts instead of one, it's even harder (and if only from the psychologic perspective) if this process is "titled" with a lousy comment.

Comment: I use that space to even recommend something to OP, i find the summary section to be very helpful when editing. @BoltClock , and yes sometimes i put *fixed formatting* but most of the times if not all the time its for when i actually just fixed formatting n_n'

Comment: Thanks for the nudge.  I'm a new <2k editor -- about 10 edits so far -- and I've been a little lazy, doing a shoddy job on 3-4 of my summaries.  _My_ problem is that I'm anxious to get the blasted text off my screen, having spent 3-5 passes understanding tortured wording and spotty formatting.  I will take a deep breath (8 in, 8 out, repeat), and give my seniors something to leave your blood pressures where they belong.  :-)

Comment: @Prune: You don't have to spend as much time on your summary as you do the edit - but definitely give reviewers more to go on than just "improved formatting", especially when your edit does *something else* altogether. For example, if your edit clarifies a question by rewriting the text but doesn't touch the formatting, you can just say you clarified the question, and that would be a vast improvement over the placeholder already simply because a copy edit and a formatting edit are two different things.

Comment: I admit that I do this when making my edits simply because I'm not sure what would be a better phrase. If anyone could come up with a better wording for that typing of suggestion then that would be very helpful :).

Comment: I'm guilty of this `fixed formatting` edit summary. But that's because that's what my edit is. I fixed the formatting. If I improved other things on the post I add, `minor improvements on grammar\spelling` etc. Is this incorrect?

Comment: If the edit I made is very obvious, I feel that `fixed XXX` is enough. However, what might be obvious to me might not be obvious to others. What do you suggest I can do to improve on this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can leave a comment under a post where they are the editor. The @-reply works for editors but it won't autocomplete.

I left this comment:

> sidenote: @XO Can you please be more precise about the comment you leave when you edit a post? *Fixed formatting* didn't really cover all your changes.

If the user responds I remove the comment or I clean-up later.

As the edit all by it self is an improvement you could accept the edit if you have verified that the edit is indeed a good fit. Or as there are enough robo-reviewers you could also move on to the next review, it probably will be accepted anyway...

Comment: Thanks for giving the sidenote example. Maybe this could be the starting point for a chat conversation, removing initial comments afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

I will confess that I am guilty of doing this sometimes and it's always in one particular situation:  The Suggested Edits review queue.  When in that queue and you select 'Improve Edit,' the system will copy the original editor's comment into your edit comment.

Many times when this happens I am making some improvements to the original edit, but then end up fixing additional problems (such as grammar) when originally only a 'fixed formatting' comment was on the edit.  I end up leaving this comment without adding what else I changed; usually because I see something in that field and without thinking just click on save.

Maybe there should be a notification when using the 'Improve Edit' button to modify the comment if left unchanged so it more accurately reflects the changes?  This would be especially helpful for us users over 2K because the improvement gets automatically approved and now that comment will remain in the history without going back into the queue...or maybe I should just be more careful.

In regards to your actual question: you should approve the edit if it is an actual improvement because the content is far more important than the edit comment.  However, you can definitely say something in the comments if you feel it should be addressed.

Comment: +1 for the suggested warning. Sadly it's not possible (I really tried!) to change ("improve") only the comment if you don't change the post itself.

Answer (score 4):

> apart from Skip the lazy or cowardly solution

As I found out, ***Skip*** is may also be a **cheap and honest** solution. If reviewers have to do a lot of work on a suggestion and therefore better skip it, the suggesting user has to wait longer for a decision. But I'm not sure how (and if) to prove this...

Comment: For what it's worth, rene's suggestion to skip robo-reviewer-prone reviews has had a fuller discussion that I started [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292007/how-to-encourage-attentive-suggested-edit-reviewers-to-skip-every-straightforwar).

Comment: I agree that skip  is a cheat & honest solution.  Especially in cases where you aren't sure if it's a true improvement, usually in regards to a code edit in a language you aren't familiar.