# Multiple edits rejected by same person

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have a bit of a complaint to make.

I've been trying to edit a lot of posts, to help contribute to the SO community and get reputation, but I've been seeing a lot of the same people reviewing my posts and downvoting them. Most of my edits are to add clarification to badly-worded or not-explained (just a block of code) questions, or to fix grammar for non-English speakers.

But I get frustrated when I got three downvotes on consecutive edits just now. I thought I'd like to get some feedback.

@Deena just rejected this edit (and two others of mine just now), for example:

```
originally there are 2*3 list items as output, however after xs ++ ys, it become lose bracket and become 6 list items, how to add back bracket every 3 list items

input

    [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
output

    [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]]
if input 3  , bracket every 3 list items

in most simple situation is

    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

output

    [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

To this:

```
Originally there are two sets of three (2*3) list items as output.

However, after xs ++ ys, it will lose the brackets and become 6 list items.

How would I add back the brackets after every 3 list items?

Input:

    [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]

Output:

    [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]]

If input 3, bracket every 3 list items.

In the most simple situation, I would like to input something like this:

    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

and get this output:

    [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]

How could I do this?

(added tags "grouping" and "brackets")
```

I thought I tried to clarify the question and make it more understandable in more proper English. What did I do wrong?

I would hope it's just erratic rejecting (most of the people who have rejected mine have many more rejections than approvals), especially because most of my edits have been approved. But it may just be bad editing skills.

Thanks for any tips!

**Edit**: Kind of an afterthought, but I just wanted to add that most of the people who reject have rejected the vast majority of the edits, probably not looking at them closely to see the fine details. For example, @andrewsi rejected my edit (that got approved) and he accepted 2131 edits and rejected *17692* edits: That means for every every nine edits, he rejects an average of (over) 8! I guess it's erratic rejecting or very high standards.

Comment: Here are the edits in question: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9883222 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9883181 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9883161

Comment: Some of your edits are adding tags which do not help the question, tags such as `bracket`.  Then there are others, `function`, `parameters`, `return`.  None of those help.

Comment: Yeah but you know, could have just improved the edit and removed the tags. Tags weren't the only thing that the OP edited. Unless people are reviewing edits based on the tags alone and completely ignoring everything else. [The earliest of the three](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9883161) in particular makes *no* tag changes whatsoever, and I'm failing to see how it's anything but a vast improvement.

Comment: @Daedalus In http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9883181, I thought `function`, `parameters`, and `return` were relevant ... are they not? It's also more relevant than the OP's `arrays`, `methods`, `variables`, and `for-loops` --- those were general-programming terms. I thought mine were more specific to the question.

Comment: @jlam55555: Those tags are mostly generic and while they may describe the question, they don't *categorize* it, since many languages share roughly the same set of concepts where all of these tags would fit. It's OK for a question to contain only one or two tags if those are the only tags that categorize it. For example, a JavaScript question that doesn't involve any library probably only needs a [javascript] tag.

Comment: @BoltClock Ok then I get that part ... but as you said earlier, because I edited the posts, wouldn't it make more sense to improve the edit by changing the tags to keep it on-topic? (to answer my original question, why was it *rejected*?)

Comment: I wish I knew. I don't understand how your edits deviate from author intent or fail to improve readability. Maybe the reviewers don't understand what good grammar is - in which case, what do they think they're doing by reviewing? Oh, right, grinding for badges.

Comment: @BoltClock For [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9883161) at least, I know I voted to reject because I thought it would fall under the idea of "don't polish turds".

Comment: @resueman: That's... a good point. I remember previous discussions recommending that particular rejection reason for turd-polishing, but it's pretty clear that it doesn't send that message *at all*.

Comment: @BoltClock and resueman: By "turd-polishing", you mean attempting to turn something hopeless into something useful (right?). If you're advising against this, then I *shouldn't* edit low-quality posts like that one?

Comment: @jlam55555: Yes, because these questions are likely to be deleted and you'd lose your +2 rep and have wasted your time as a result. Your time is better spent editing where it counts.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for your help and feedback, but last thing... would you deem a post like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182885/homework-vb-net-how-to-change-backcolor-on-form-when-you-press-start) worth editing?

Comment: @jlam55555: absolutely not :)

Comment: @BoltClock: Trying to turn something useless into something useful *and completely failing*, that would be a more appropriate description of turd-polishing. Because the failure to achieve that aim is critical for it being a waste instead of a much-lauded success.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Exactly - I don't see why we couldn't have a separate rejection reason spelling that out instead of making people reinterpret an existing one.

Comment: concerning your edit just now, the fact (if it is true) that @andrewsi is willing to review so many, to me suggests he deserves a trophy or something. Though I found the few edit attempts (that I read) to be more comforting to read compared to the original, I too would probably reject them. Note, sample size like 3, so it is way small, and not representative of much at all. Like I said, I liked your versions a bit better. But I like to power read through questions, not worry about someone putting lipstick on a pig. To each their own style. Thank goodness for you, and andrewsi

Comment: Regarding your edit, I expect that most of those with high reject counts (including myself) have such daunting stats not because we reject the vast majority of edits we *see*, but because we **skip** the majority of edits we see in review, and [only actually review those that really need us specifically](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292007/4099598). There's no relaxation of standards necessary. Quite the contrary.