# Improving the quality of tag only edit approvals

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, tag-badges

I did a preliminary search on this, it's probably a dup, but I can't find it. Besides, it's just to open this idea for discussion.

I was talking to an OP in comments to clarify the question and noticed this suggested edit pop up, then noticed it was approved.

[image]

Beyond being clairvoyant I don't see how anyone could know if this is related to asp.net with this amount of information.

Now, it's not the end of the world. But I am always wondering how to improve things (usually my ideas are not on the most practical side, so please forgive me if this is a clanger).

**So the discussion is:**

Is there a way to help catch dodgy tag edits?
Should one of the editors have a badge in that tag for the edit to be approved?   Would that kill the edit queue, cause an enormous back up. 
  It might delay the approval long enough for the OP to come back on line and reject or approve it.

Does anybody have a better idea, or do we just leave it as is.

Thoughts?

*I've taken a screen shot to reduce the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta) and to avoid link rot.*

Comment: Do we agree that it isn't related to asp.net? datagridview is a winform control, not a webcontrol...

Comment: @rene that's what I was thinking. I'm using this as an example though, not intending it to be a focal point.

Comment: Reviewers just don't press the Skip button often enough.  The review system is very clumsy, it should be push and not pull.  In my ideal world, the machine pays attention to the normal rules it uses to select posts for the front page (tag favorites and post history) and lights up a button when there are *relevant* reviews.  Stuff I actually care about.  No more than 10 either so it looks like a finite job.

Comment: @HansPassant I couldn't agree more. I think the skip button is overlooked also. If I don't understand a tag, I skip it. If I don't understand the subject I skip it. If I do understand the subject, but am too tired to make a decision, I leave the queue and come back later when I have the brain energy, which means I often do not reach the daily quotas of reviews.

Comment: Not only is the tag incorrect, the suggestion is woefully incomplete (confusing wording, has "thanks", capitalization).  On those grounds alone I would never approve it.  Maybe "improve edit" if I thought the tag suggestion was absolutely essential, but probably reject as "no improvment whatsoever".  *grumble *grumble robo-reviewers.

Comment: I'm in the minority here but I recently started skipping all edits I would otherwise approve. Rejections are far more valuable and anything that should get approve is going to without my help

Comment: Personally, I just skip or reject if I also see something else wrong in the post.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Perhaps [not quite as much of a minority as you think](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292007/how-to-encourage-attentive-suggested-edit-reviewers-to-skip-every-straightforwar)....

Comment: @mikeTheLiar excellent idea, I'll try that.

Comment: @NathanTuggy well I guess I'm in good company then!

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume for a moment that every editor is expected to add some value to the post. Once visible, the post should be better.

For fact, the suggested edit review queue is *famous* for its robo-reviewers. No matter what you throw at them, it will get approved.

I don't think restricting certain reviews to only eligible reviewers will prevent these kind of mishaps. And it does keep a possible valid re-tag into the queue longer, preventing the correct audience to see the question or for visitors to find it.

In the case you use as an example adding the tag [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) brings in a vast majority of users that will quickly judge if the tag is correct and if not retag.

If there is something to be done, maybe it is in the tag added in relation to how it will change the visibility and its search rating. If a tag-only edit doesn't change the audience (in size or context) much then a notice could be shown to reviewers. But that is about it.

There is bot that runs in the [SO Tavern](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks) that tries to catch suggested-edit-reviews that have an rejection vote. Based on the fact that all reviewers happily approve, an rejection probably means that review needs more attention.

Concluding: There is not much we can do without having a blowback on those who are genuinely trying to add value.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer this. There's so many catches in place in Stack, that I'm not aware of, I really am not in a position to make suggestions. It's kinda arrogant of me to think that all these brains haven't already thought of all these things.  When this bot catches the edit reviews with a rejected vote, what actually happens?

Comment: Not much happens, the bot reports it, in the hope regulars in the room are quick enough to make a judgement call and get their rejections in.

Comment: I think I should worry less and just get about my business of looking at Q and As. I do find some of the meta discussions interesting, but it's not the main purpose for me. Cheers.

Comment: Nah, you're doing fine @Yvette your question is OK and legit. We need people that pay attention to these cases and bring in several and new ways looking at all matters. This topic has several rough edges and I personally hope that someone else will write a better answer than mine.

Comment: well, there is no definitive answer, it was to throw around ideas and I learnt something new by your answer. After looking at your profile, you've encouraged me to be more attentive and review on the close vote queue ;)

Comment: or, being above 2K, we expect your hammer to set in when you know things are wrong and fix them. You probably know a hell of a lot more than the reviewers, @Yvette

Comment: @Drew  But to approve suggested don't you need 2000? which means the hammers are not working. And sure, I did fix it. I waited for the OP, when he didn't respond, I edited it. The thing is, obviously, I'm aware of this case.. I'm referring more to the ones that are missed. As an aside, I thought the question was going to be far more interesting than it turned out to be.. hence my interest. The person who suggested the edit thought it would get more attention adding the tag! I'm like what the deuce!

Comment: the hammers dont work some times

Comment: I think that picture snippet represents an interesting question concept. It would be of interest to you and me. I have taken a ton of interest in questions that just don't interest the common man (or woman) in this rush by aging format. Some of the best questions I have seen have view count of 7 after 2 hours. Psychology use cases. Means the title or tags scared the rep things away

Comment: @Drew true true. My programming skills are still developing, but I love trying to problem solve, work out algorithms. The excitement when you think how  am I going to make that work... or when you have made it work, how the hell can I make that ugly mess more elegant! hahaha when I don't want anyone to see my code, I know it desperately need beautifying. And as for the question, different people mean different things by the word `thesis`. That's the *whole global interaction and attempt to interpret online without nuances thing.*