# Reviewers Disagreeing about Reviews

Tags: support, review-queues, comments

**TLDR**
**What procedures are recommended when disagreeing with a another user's review?**

---

*forgive me if there is a dup*

**case study**

I have a ping that leads me to this question and the comment below:

[LinearLayout with style and without orientation issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327029/linearlayout-with-style-and-without-orientation-issue)

[image]

It is about a suggested edit I rejected and edited 14 hours previously:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20327029/revisions

I had to actually go to the commenter's page, activity where they'd reviewed the edit to see what I actually rejected.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10204487

Now the comment says:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - Did I miss something or did you just add a tag you like and called that critical issue? Anyway for those minor edits I consider it very rude to reject-edit. There is an approve-edit mechanism for that.

ok the critical issue was this:

> But, can I resolve my problem, without disable warning?

I edited it again.

Is a comment always the best way to deal with this situation?   [Let me comment on reviews (and notify the reviewers)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298174/let-me-comment-on-reviews-and-notify-the-reviewers)

I'm assuming there are protocols and that these would vary depending upon the issue of disagreement.

**What is the best way to deal with a fellow reviewer when you do not agree with their review?**

---

If you're still reading only continue if you're truly bored.

*Personally this comment wasted a lot of time for me to figure out what was going on and it would've been better for me had the commenter fixed the critical issue and left me in blissful ignorance ..

... and I wasn't going to get into a debate about:

... the validity of rejecting an edit and then replacing a tag with a more suitable tag..

.. or the fact that reviewers get tired and I missed the poorly worded sentence ..

.. is a poorly worded sentence a critical issue ...

.. when is it rude to reject edits (which would make an interesting meta discussion) ...

...  And since when do reviewers think it's ok to approve minor edits..*

It would be good if there was a link to a Meta post that users could use as a link in a comment for this type of situation given noise in comments being an issue.

Comment: Re: "forgive me if there is a dup" See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed)

Comment: @user193661 haha yeh, hilarious post. I see what you mean.. should read *I couldn't find a dup, but am sure there must be given the immense resources of Meta* :)

Comment: Let me quickly comment on that. Your edit is perfectly fine. What surprised me is that you decided to reject the suggested edit. The edit was reasonable and fixed all the issues. You decided that `android-styles` would be a good additional tag. Fair enough, but why do you not give credit to the author of the original edit by improving instead of rejecting? After all you have used all of their improvements in your own edit.

Comment: @cel because I didn't think it was a good edit. And I'm rejecting edits I think are too minor, or in this case, he removed a tag that should've been replaced with the appropriate tag. I'm trying not to reward people for a job half done. There is a really good link that explains my ethos.. I'll find it for you.. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292007/how-to-encourage-attentive-suggested-edit-reviewers-to-skip-every-straightforwar

Comment: @cel this is also something I am aware of and it's un/fortunate for the editor that I reviewed the edit.. also I have a special interest in the android tag, so a double whammy. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309667/improving-the-quality-of-tag-only-edit-approvals

Comment: @MrsEd, I think you are too critical here. By my standards this was a good edit and the user would have improved SO. There were no major problems left. The missing tag I would consider optional. After all tagging is often highly subjective. I agree that your edit made the question even better, but rejecting is too harsh IMO. We surly do not want to stop these people from editing stackoverflow. Rejected edits may be a motivation for some to improve, for most it will be mostly a bad experience that'll stop them spending time on editing in future.

Comment: @cel: I disagree. Untagging is easy, properly re-tagging is hard. But in this case the untagger should really have found the proper tag. And failing there *was* enough to reject, the rest wasn't good enough to override that.

Comment: "I'm rejecting edits I think are too minor" - There is your problem. And you complain about other people wasting *your* time?

Comment: @GEOCHET: It's more accurately described as: I'm rejecting because the edit is a waste of time, though a valuable edit could easily have been done instead.

Comment: @GEOCHET how is rejecting edits that are too minor wasting time for me/others?

Comment: Because people put time into those edits and you are investing your time into making their time worthless. If the edit improves the post, no matter how small the contribution, you should be approving it.

Comment: @GEOCHET That is highly debatable.. You have been around long enough to know this.. just because that is your opinion, it doesn't make it the right thing to do.

Comment: That is a double edged sword. Your opinion is just that as well.

In my case, I want positive contributions to not be stomped on by pedantic, vindictive gestapo reviewers. In your case, you are overly concerned by people not contributing to your standard and when they don't meet your arbitrary and unpublished guidelines, you delete their valid positive contributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users tend to disagree all the time with each other about what is a good review, a valuable edit, a correct flag, a deserved vote.

One of the great things of the community moderation model is the transparency and reversibility of actions.

That does come with a pay-off. Now and then your own actions, which are of the highest standards, are scrutinized by users with different higher standards. This is where the learning part starts for all parties involved.

Some users go this far that they keep an eye on the posts that they reviewed to see if they reached consensus (I wrote a [user script to make that easier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history/251508#251508)).
Users watching the active tab of their favorite tag will see all edits and might check and react to that.
Some users simply stumble onto something that make them frown.

With all this happening, some users simply redo/roll-back/re-vote whatever they feel their fellow members did wrong. Some users have the urge to get hold of such user to verify if the action they took was deliberate.

The easiest place to get such an issue resolved is by leaving a comment, explaining why you would have made a different decision, move the discussion to chat if you need to go back and forth on the issue. If the user is known to be active in chat, you can ping them there. Be prepared to exchange arguments based on facts/meta posts and personal experience but also [agree to disagree](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=1952819#1952819).

Just accept that not two users are the same. After the dust is settled make sure to clean-up comments and *live long and prosper*.

Comment: I agree about cleaning up the comments, going into a discussion is a good idea. Are there other options?

Comment: No, that is about it. In sever cases of vandalizing edits you can flag for a moderator but that is not the case you describe. I go *meh* if someone disagrees with me, that is the easy way out.

Comment: Thanks rene, I actually wasn't sure what people usually did with this. Good to know, thanks. I usually don't keep track of my reviews. So found it strange, it's interesting to see you wrote a script! hahaha