# Why was this particular edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

The link is dead and I updated it using WayBackMachine, and it seems 3 out of 4 reviewers think the edit is "superfluous".

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11794410

Comment: I would guess they didn't read the edit comment, and only noticed your pointless formatting change.

Comment: They must have been looking in the ['rendered output' view](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a42mS.jpg) I guess. :/

Comment: Maybe also because the link doesn't lead to a 404 but to the home page of the website... I think this edit was valid.

Comment: Hard to guess, they probably just don't know what an archive.com link looks like.  It does look too much like a copy/paste mistake.  I changed it for you.

Comment: One of those "Rejecters" has an astonishing high Reject rate - even for good (IMO) edits such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11794350). On his first page of reviews, he's the only rejecter-out-of-5 for a lot of reviews. What's that all about?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a positive (should be approved) suggested edit review, only negative. One could easily get the edit review badges by just rejecting everything.

Comment: @RadLexus If you reject everything you cannot fail an audit

Comment: Lets stay on topic here, its not 1 reviewer that rejects large number of posts, but it is a valid edit that has been rejected

Comment: @RadLexus some reviewers possibly like what was proposed in [Encouraging attentive suggested edit reviewers to skip every uncontroversial review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292007/839601), _"skipping anything that would likely be accepted just fine anyway by the unstoppable train of auto-acceptances"_

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As several commenters have mentioned, the reviewers *likely* just viewed the *Rendered Output* from your edit which looks like this (image credit @Wai Ha Lee):

[image]

Which on the surface *appears* to be a superfluous edit; however, reviewers should consider at least 2 of the following:

1. Rendered Output
2. Markdown
3. Editor's comment

Here they appear to have just viewed the rendered output, and paid your comment no attention (and weren't aware they could and/or couldn't be bothered to view the markdown).

As far as I'm concerned: **you couldn't have done anything better**! I don't think it's necessary / right to have to add "MAKE SURE YOU CHECK THE MARKDOWN VIEW" in your edit comment.