# "Reject and Edit" - Reviewers with oddly high "reject" numbers that supply similar edits afterwards?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Looking though my edit history I came across an [odd edit rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19810257): When I tried to find out what I should have done better and looked at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50485416/revisions) I saw only one edit, which was rather similar to mine (with minor deviations).

Then I noticed that the editor in question has a rather high rejection ratio (rejecting over 8 out of 10 reviewed edits) which does strike me a rather odd - of course, they might just have the bad luck of getting to review all the crap edits, or they might skip instead of appoving, but I feel those chances are slim.

All in all I got a "Nice edit, now it's mine *Yoink*" vibe here (even though there were a few points that I now agree with the editor, e.g. not changing *Virtualise* to *Virtualize*), and I wonder if there is a policy on this (i.e. is it OK to go *Yoink* yourself once you hit 2k Rep?), because I think those things can feel rather discouraging to new editors.

Comment: Having a high rejection ratio is not odd. The reason we have a review queue is because there are a high number of terrible edits.

Comment: If a question is deemed closable, suggesting edits that do not bring the question out of "closable" territory is not a good thing to do. If the reviewer was going to vote to close, it makes sense that they would reject your suggested edit.

Comment: related: [Encouraging attentive suggested edit reviewers to skip every uncontroversial review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292007/839601)

Comment: @gnat Ah, I wasn't aware that this is an issue. This explains things, thanks.

Comment: @yivi See [the third definition here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yoink#Verb).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hmmm I was a bit harsh with this reject/edit, however it was over a year ago that this took place, nowadays I would just skip this review and focus on the really bad edits.

I should have approved/improved this edit (or at least *explained* my rejection in the summary), *if* I remember rightly which there is every possibility that I don't, the *rejection* was caused by the changing of *"virtualise"* to *"virtualize"*. At the time of reviewing this I was consistently seeing edits of the forms:

- *"colour"* to *"color"*
- *"-ise"* to *"-ize"*
- *"-nt"* to *"-ned"*
- ... (you get the picture)

The way I see it, it is not our place to force one form of English over another onto a user, regardless of whether or not we agree with the way that it was written.

Sorry that you ended up a victim as a result of this, like I said, nowadays I would've skipped so I can get rid of the real rubbish that's in the queue. Although I stand by my high reject rate, there are ***a lot*** of bad edits and there are a lot of robo-reviewers that approve every edit they see, even when these edits clearly should be rejected, those posts are where my focus is now.

Comment: To reinforce what I said about robo-reviewers in my answer, I wholeheartedly agree with the [related post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292007/encouraging-attentive-suggested-edit-reviewers-to-skip-every-uncontroversial-rev) gnat linked to,and the idea of: *"skipping anything that would likely be accepted just fine anyway by the unstoppable train of auto-acceptances"*

Comment: Fair enough - as I already mentioned, I wholeheartedly agree that changing Virtuali**s**e to Virtuali**z**e was very unnecessary (to be honest, I *think* that part of the edit was an unfortunate subconscious one while fixing real spelling errors/grammar issues). I'd like to apologize to you for bringing this up (especially after so long), when I stumbled across it today and looked at the subsequent edit I thought "WTF did I do wrong? It can't just be spelling, can it?". I also was not aware of the issue of rampant "auto-acceptances" in reviews. Sorry again.

Answer (score 10):

You've fixed a lot of grammar mistakes, but introduced an inconsistency (an application in the start, the application in the end), and made an unnecessary change (capital letter after colon, not needed, especially if we assume British English).

That's not good, since you should not introduce inconsistencies or make unnecessary changes.

It's entirely valid to reject the edit because of it, but preserve all the good changes you did make. If he'd accepted the edit, you wouldn't know you did anything wrong. And if he'd rejected it outright, the good parts would've been lost.

Personally, I think these things are too minor to reject an edit over, but that's open for debate, since if you don't reject, the editor doesn't get feedback.

Comment: Good points, I'll take them to heart. That said, the ability include information as to *why exactly* an edit was rejected might be an useful feature idea (the standard message of "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed." didn't really help me there)

Comment: @CharonX You can consider submitting a request, but I doubt it'll get much support. To work around the fact that this is not possible, I tend to adjust the edit description and note deficiencies in the proposed edit, but unfortunately that's somewhat rare.

Comment: "If he'd accepted the edit, you wouldn't know you did anything wrong." You cannot just claim this. I check the review of every single edit I make. If somebody accepts and edits my edit, I read what changes they made, to understand what I did wrong, or could've done better. This has been very helpful several times. However, when my edits are rejected and edited, it makes me unhappy, and uninterested in making more edits. If these changes made to my suggested edits are small, I just get annoyed.